# Can the return type of the function be obtained from within the function?

Tags: c++, c++11, trailing-return-type

Can the return type of a function be obtained in a simple way within the function?

For example, given:

```
template <typename P>
static inline auto foo(P p) -> typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*p)>::type {
    typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*p)>::type f{};  // <-- here

    ...
}
```

In C++11 can I refer to the big nasty return type of `foo`, within `foo` itself, without repeating it, at the line marked `// <-- here`?

Comment: In C++14, you can remove the trailing return type instead, and use `return f;` to deduce the return type.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Call the function with a `decltype`.

```
decltype(foo(p)) f{};
```

Comment: life made easy by `decltype` ;)